# Access data files in Docker image from host

Tags: docker

I know that mounting/using a volume when running an image will overwrite the directory in the container with the directory on the host.

I'm wondering if this can be done the other way around.

I have data in `my-image` which was created during `docker build`.

```
docker run -dit --volume ~/data:/usr/data my-image
```

From the command above, the host `~/data` directory will map inside of the Docker container to the `/usr/data` directory. I want the opposite behavior, I want the container `/usr/data` directory to map to the host `~/data` (essentially overwriting anything inside the host directory `~/data`).

Is this possible?

Comment: Is the directory empty?

Comment: Probably better to use `docker cp` to copy files out.

Comment: Could you explain a use case for such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas:

## Link/mount volume folder

1. Turn a folder inside the container into a volume (e.g. by marking it as a `VOLUME` inside the `Dockerfile`)
2. On the host, link or mount the volume folder into the desired location
   (depending on what works and what you need).
   This is possible because volumes live inside `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`
   --you just need to find the relevant folder by inspecting the container.

The benefit here is that you can access the data even if the container is not running.

## Use FUSE, e.g. `sshfs`

A more "generic" solution would be to use something like `sshfs`.

Obviously it requires your container to run `ssh` and to establish
the connection before the data from the container can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

As one solution is suggested by @Tomasz which is also possible,
But before posting my answer I will share our use case why we doing this.

we map  `/data/` directory of the host at creation time with an empty directory of the container `/root/data/` and then copy a remote code from `/home/tempdata/data/` to `/root/data` of the container which overrides anything in the mount directory i.e `~/data` of the host during boot time.

So as a result, the user will get the latest code from the container to host the directory which means a form of overriding a bit tricky way to achieve the opposite case.

```
docker build -t override .

docker run -it --rm --privileged -p 8081:8080 --name tt -v ~/data/:/root/data override
```

[image: response from docker container after boot]

Here is the Dockerfile based on alpine

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /etc/supervisord.d

RUN apk  add --no-cache supervisor git npm 

# general config for supervisord
RUN echo  $'[supervisord] \n\
[unix_http_server] \n\
file = /tmp/supervisor.sock \n\
chmod = 0777 \n\
chown= nobody:nogroup \n\
[supervisord] \n\
logfile = /tmp/supervisord.log \n\
logfile_maxbytes = 50MB \n\
logfile_backups=10 \n\
loglevel = info \n\ 
pidfile = /tmp/supervisord.pid \n\
nodaemon = true \n\
umask = 022 \n\
identifier = supervisor \n\
[supervisorctl] \n\
serverurl = unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock \n\
[rpcinterface:supervisor] \n\
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface \n\
[include] \n\
files = /etc/supervisord

# clone remote code so that can override local code of the user specified directory 

RUN git clone https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/bluemix-hello-node /home/tempdata/data/

# copy code from container directory to host mount directory
RUN echo $'#!/bin/ash \n\
echo "********************************8" \n\
mkdir -p /root/data/ \n\
mkdir -p /home/tempdata/ \n\
echo "*******Overiding /data/ of host machine ****" \n\
# this will override host machine files like if server.js modified on host this will overide with remote server.js
cp  -r /home/tempdata/data/ /root/ \n\ 
cd /root/data/; npm i; npm start' >> /root/override.sh

RUN echo $'[supervisord] \n\
nodaemon=true \n\
[program:override] \n\
command=/root/override.sh \n\
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1 \n\
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0MB \n\
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 0 \n\
stderr_logfile=/dev/fd/2 \n\
redirect_stderr=true \n\
autorestart=false \n\
startretries=0 \n\
exitcodes=0 ' >> /etc/supervisord.d/override.conf


RUN chmod +x /root/override.sh


EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["supervisord", "--nodaemon", "--configuration", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```